# How can I add JButtons in a DefaultListModel?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I am making a battleship game and I'm trying to figure out a way to control buttons in a pane so that I can drag drop them and keep track of their indexes with a default list model.If I add string or ImageIcons it works fine but with buttons I get something different.

Here's my code:

```
public class ListModelExample extends JPanel {

  JList list;
  DefaultListModel model;
  int counter = 15;

  public ListModelExample() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    model = new DefaultListModel();
    list = new JList(model);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(list);
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add Element");
    JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove Element");
    final JButton button = new JButton("button");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      model.addElement(button);

    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.addElement(button);
        counter++;    

      }
    });
    removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (model.getSize() > 0)
          model.removeElementAt(0);
      }
    });

    add(pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(addButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(removeButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
  }

  public static void main(String s[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("List Model Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new ListModelExample());
    frame.setSize(260, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

If I add Buttons I get this result:

[image: Result of adding buttons in the pane]

**So my question is: How is it possible to make buttons appear normally and not as text in a default list model?**

Comment: why do you want to add buttons to list?

Comment: you can use the "setName(String n)" method.. 
add a static counter.. and for each button convert it to string and set the button name with it.. then check by the button name his location and all things you want..

Comment: Components should *never* be placed in a Swing component model. 1+ to mKorbel's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- this could be done only by `Renderer`, put only `String` value to the `DefaultListModel`
- don't put any `JComponents` to the `XxxModel`
- I'd be use `JPanel` with `JButtons` instead of `JList` as containers (required to change `getScrollableBlockIncrement` / `getScrollableUnitIncrement` for natural scrolling in compare with `JList` or `JTable`)

example about both a.m. ways

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListButtons extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ListButtons() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        model.addElement(createButtons("one"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("two"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("three"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("four"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("five"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("six"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("seven"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("eight"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("nine"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("ten"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("eleven"));
        model.addElement(createButtons("twelwe"));
        JList list = new JList(model);
        list.setCellRenderer(new PanelRenderer());
        JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(list);
        final JScrollBar scrollBar = scroll1.getVerticalScrollBar();
        scrollBar.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("JScrollBar's current value = " + scrollBar.getValue());
            }
        });
        add(scroll1);
        JScrollPane scroll2 = new JScrollPane(createPanel());
        add(scroll2);        
        final JScrollBar scrollBar1 = scroll2.getVerticalScrollBar();
        scrollBar1.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("JScrollBar's current value = " + scrollBar1.getValue());
            }
        });

    }

    public static JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 1, 1));
        panel.add(createButtons("one"));
        panel.add(createButtons("two"));
        panel.add(createButtons("three"));
        panel.add(createButtons("four"));
        panel.add(createButtons("five"));
        panel.add(createButtons("six"));
        panel.add(createButtons("seven"));
        panel.add(createButtons("eight"));
        panel.add(createButtons("nine"));
        panel.add(createButtons("ten"));
        panel.add(createButtons("eleven"));
        panel.add(createButtons("twelwe"));
        return panel;
    }

    public static JButton createButtons(String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                ListButtons frame = new ListButtons();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(270, 200);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class PanelRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JButton renderer = (JButton) value;
            renderer.setBackground(isSelected ? Color.red : list.getBackground());
            return renderer;
        }
    }
}
```